# C++ phisics simulation math. How do I make soft (fading) phisics interaction

Tags: c++, math

Sorry for "informative" title, I spend like 30 minutes trying figure how to ask this.
I have trees in my game and wind, and I want them to be affected by it. It all done, but when wind is too strong, explosions near by, the tree bends too far and it looks freaky. 
So basicly I need my 
**X**, which is the ammount of displacement, at small amounds to be more or less proportional to 
**Y**-amount of wind in that direction. But when wind is stronger, X to be not that much bigger.
Talking 1D now.

So when Y = 100, X would be like 10. When Y=200 I want X like 18, 
Y=300, X=25
and so on. But Y should never be bigger then certian number. For example 50.
So when Y=20000, X would be like 45.
Y=50000 X=49.

Numbers are just example, I just want some math to make bending softer.

Basicly I need to know how to drow this graph with one formula:
[image]

In the picture X and Y changed roles from what i explaned upstairs. Here X is wind and Y is ammount of displacement.

Comment: So you want a [logarithmic scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale) between your `Y` and `X` values?

Comment: Eeee, maybe (dont know what is logarithmic scale), Ill look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to find a function, which converges to 50 in infinity. For example, `1/-x` converges to 0, so `50 + 1/-x` converges to 50. `arctan(x)` converges to `pi/2`, so you can as well use `arctan(x) / (pi/2) * 50`.

Logarithm's graph looks good, but it converges to infinity in infinity, so it will cross your 50 boundary at some time (unless you can specify maximum force, which can be applied to a tree).

Anyway, I'd rather find a function, which models the force change nicely to some high value of X (say, Y=20000), and then clamp all higher values to 50. By the look, most of the games does just that.

Comment: 50 is a magic number?

Comment: OP gave 50 as an example, so did I :)